# Typing problem with flatMap in angular and rxjs 6

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, functional-programming, rxjs

I am learning rxjs in angular.  I downloaded the project from a tutorial and one class fails to compile.  I tried to correct it, assuming some library has evolved, but I failed.  I simplified the code to the bare minimum and I still can't understand why I get an error.  It is a typescript error given via the Intellij IDE.

I get an error on line 7 below:

```
import { flatMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export class TestClass {
    a$ = of('dummy').pipe( // Observable<string>
        flatMap(s => of(s)), // Observable<string>
        map<string, string>(s => s) // Observable<string>  <-- ERROR HERE
    );

    b$ = of('dummy').pipe( // Observable<string>
        flatMap(s => of(s)), // Observable<string> or Observable<Observable<string>> ?
        map<Observable<string>, Observable<string>>(os => os)
    );
}
```

The `map()`s are just to see what type is expected after `flatMap()`.

As far as I understand flatMap, you have an `Observable<T>` on entry, you map each item `T` to an `Observable<T>` and flatMap flattens the whole back to an `Observable<T>`.

But there is an error in a$.
[image]

While b$ compiles fine.  It seems that `flatMap` doesn't flatten the content and produces an `Observable<Observable<T>>`.  The next `map()` expects `Observable<T>` as items.

So what is going on?  Is there something I haven't understood in `flatMap()` or `pipe()`?  Or is something funny going on with my compiler or my IDE and I am getting erroneous error messages?

**Update**

In the end it was an issue with typescript giving a fake error.
And my confidence in my understanding of functional programming is restored.

Comment: My TSLint shows me no error on `a$`, but an error on `b$`. Have you tried to restart your IDE ? It sometimes happen when you do some complex typing manipulations...

Comment: Thank you.  I had tried to restart the IDE and clear node_modules.  It didn't help.  However by upgrading the version of typescript and tslint (and a few others) I now have the opposite error, a$ passes, b$ shows an error.  It seems there was some issue with some version of tslint that caused that error.

Comment: Please do not add solved to your question. Either accept existing answer, post your own answer, or delete the question altogether if it is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

`of('dummy')` creates an Observable and emits the string `'dummy'` down the pipe.
`flatMap` (as per docs [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) is an alias for `mergeMap`), will receive what the previous operator/static method sent down the pipe, map it to whatever you specified on the projector function and then flatten it, merging to outer Observable (as per docs [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/flatMap)).

In your case with `flatMap(s => of(s))`, the string `'dummy'` will be mapped to an Observable, and, before returned and sent down the pipe, `flatMap` will merge it to the outer Observable, so you don't have an `Observable<Observable<string>>` and just a simple `Observable<string>`.

RxJs operators are expected to receive Observables and return Observables down the pipe (if one of them, like map, doesn't explicit return an Observable, RxJs does it for you behind the curtains). So, your last `map` will receive an `Observable<string>`, like expected in `b$`, not a plain `string`, as expected in `a$`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  But since the function in flatMap returns an Observable already, there is no reason for it to be wrapped in a new one.  As I said in the other comment, the error disappeard after upgrading some packages.  But you explanation sheds some light on what might have happened.  Somehow typescript didn't recognize the return type of the function in my flatMap to be an Observable so it wrapped the result in one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

My understanding of flatMap is correct and tslint is wrong on that one.

After upgrading the version of typescript and tslint (and a few others), `a$` compiled OK and `b$` results in an error, as I would expect.

It seems there is some issue with the version of tslint I used, or maybe a compatibility issue with other libraries, that resulted in a false error.

For the record, the configuration that didn't work included:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
"@angular/...": "^6.0.3",
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"ts-node": "~5.0.1",
"typescript": "~2.7.2",
"tslint": "~5.9.1"
```

The configuration that works includes:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.0",
"@angular/...": "^6.1.3",
"rxjs": "6.0.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.1",
"typescript": "~2.7.0"
"tslint": "~5.11.0",
```